# Routes conflicts in codeigniter 3

Tags: php, codeigniter

My defined routes

```
$route['search/results/(:any)'] = 'search/results/$1';
$route['search/(:any)'] = 'search/index/$1';
```

Whenever i try to access the first route it always redirects to index method?
I have tried replacing the position of index routes as well.
Here is how i am calling results route from the URL

http://localhost:8888/revam/search/results/?type=books

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Things after the question mark are going to be parsed as query parameters, not part of the route.

Comment: Yes you are right.Is there a way to handle such routes? @puddi

Answer (score 1):

Here after question mark type=books is parsing as query parameters not as route,that's its leading to index method.

One way to handle this is to update your route with something like this.

```
$route['search/results?(:any)'] = 'search/results/$1';
$route['search/(:any)'] = 'search/index/$1';
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

There is also a simpler way to solve this, since you are not calling the url by using url segments after the /search/results/ you could build your routes like this:

```
$route['search/results'] = 'search/results/$1';
$route['search/(:any)'] = 'search/index/$1';
```